# How to get the API JSON data in React-Table from props?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-table

I am new to react world, and I face the problem of calling the data from API to the column in `react-table`

Consider the code below:

```
  render() { 
        const { purchaseData } = this.props;
         console.log("Purchase Data", purchaseData)

       const columns = [
            {
              Header: "Items Id",
              accessor:"items_id",
            },
            {
              Header: "Supplier name",
              accessor:"supplier_name",
            },
            {
              Header: "Quantity",
              accessor:"quantity",
            },
        ]
return (
<div className="item-table">
   <ReactTable
      columns={columns}
      defaultPageSize={4}
      showPagination={false}
      noDataText={"No data"}
   >
   </ReactTable>
</div>
)
}
```

So I believe maybe the method of calling data was wrong according to my method, right? but how would I get the correct way?

Comment: map through response and return the objects with keys as table headings

Comment: Please follow up the official [examples](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/HEAD/docs/examples.md) or try to make a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) of your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `react-table`. You should pass data attribute for `ReactTable`.
There given example on [documentation](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#data). And given props should be `array`. On `console.log()` I see object. You can pass it like this:

```
<ReactTable
      columns={columns}
      data={[purchaseData]}
      defaultPageSize={4}
      showPagination={false}
      noDataText={"No data"}
   >
```